# Как в adobe after effects изменить порядок слоев в нужном месте?

Tags: after-effects

Как в adobe after effects изменить порядок слоев в нужном месте.
У меня есть 3 картинки, каждая по очереди перемещается в цент увеличивается и должна быть по верх других, но ни как не пойму как это сделать.

Кто работал с adobe after effect подскажите, как э
то делается, как это называется. Пол дня сижу не могу найти как такое сделать.